# How to get <? super T> from T

Tags: java, generics

I have a method looks like this.

```java
static <T> void doSomethind(final Class<? super T> type, final T instance) {

}
```

And there is a method for finding a appropriate super class for T or Object.

```java
static Class<?> getType(final Object instance) {

    // returns a Class which is parent of given instance.
}
```

I ain't even sure the `<? super T>` part is necessary or not. Can it be `<T>`?

```java
static void doSomething(final Object instance) {

    final Class<?> type = getType(instance);

   // how can I call <T>doSomething(Class<T>, t)?
}
```

Or

```java
static <T> void doSomething(final T instance) {

    final Class<?> type = getType(instance);

    // how can I call <T>doSomething(Class<T>, t)?
}
```

Question is how can I call `doSomething(Class, Object)` method?

**UPDATE**

I'm so sorry. But I even don't know what I'm asking. So I decided to tell the fool(full) story.

In [javax.xml.bind.Marshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html), there are methods look like `marshal(Object, XXX)` such as

1. marshal(Object, ContentHandler)
2. marshal(Object, File)
3. and so on.

And I thought I can make a generic utility method using reflection like this.

```java
public static <T> marshal(Marshaller marshaller, Object element,
                          Class<? super T> targetType, T target)
    throws VariousNastyExceptions {

    // like a boss, huh?
    Marshaller.class.getMethod("marshal", Object.class, targetType)
        .invoke(marshaller, element, target);
}

// still not sure about <? super T>
```

So anyone can invoke like this.

```java
marshal(marshaller, element, OutputStream.class, output);
// say output is an instance of ByteArrayOutputStream

marshal(marshaller, element, Result.class, result);
// say the result is an instance of StreamResult
```

And then I want a new version without the `targetType`.

For that I, firstly, collected those candidates for `targetType`.

```
// InputStream.class, File.class, XMLEventWriter.class, and so on.
static final List<Class<?>> TARGET_TYPES;
static {
    final List<Class<?>> targetTypes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    for (Method method : Marshaller.class.getMethods()) {
        // if method is for marshal(Object, T) // code skipped
        targetTypes.add(method.getParameterTypes()[0]);
    }
    TARGET_TYPES = Collections.unmodifiableList(targetTypes);
}
```

Now I can fetch the `targetType` from given `Object`.

```
static Class<?> getTargetType(Object target) {

    for (Class<?> targetType : TARGET_TYPES) {
        if (targetType.isAssignableFrom(target.getClass())) {
            return targetType;
        }
    }

    return null; // don't count this for now
}
```

And I finally tried

```
// do I need a <T> here?
static void marshal(Marshaller marshaller, Object element, Object target) {

    final Class<?> targetType = getTargetType(target);

    // compiler hates this statement
    marshal(marshaller, element, targetType, target);
}
```

I just want a `Cipher` for decrypting following message.

```
method Marshallers.<T> marshal(Marshaller,Object,Class<? super T>, T) is not applicable
 (actual argument Class <CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<? super Object> by method
  invocation conversion)
```

I think I can do like this.

```
static <T> void marshal(Marshaller marshaller, Object element, T target) {

    // No ClassCastException guaranteed
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Class<? super T> targetType =
        (Class<? super T>) getTargetType(target);

    marshal(marshaller, element, targetType, target);
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way. When combining "advanced" generics with Reflection, you can be happy that it works at all. ;)

Comment: I don't even know which answer that I should accept. All up-voted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't without a warning. You need to use an unsafe cast.

```
static <T> void doSomething(final Class<T> type, final T instance) 
{
}

//here the unchecked cast warning can be suppressed. 
//It could be somewhere else though, the unchecked cast I mean. This is one solution only.
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> Class<T> getType(final T instance) 
{
    return (Class<T>) instance.getClass();
}

static <T> void doSomething(final T instance) 
{
    final Class<T> type= getType(instance);
    //call to doSomething with a type and an instance
    doSomething(type, instance);
}
```

Comment: You can do it without an unsafe cast. As you can see in answers below.

Comment: Nah, you can't. The answers below simply leave out the implementation of getType()...

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain why you need something like this?

But to invoke doSomething(Class, Object) method you can change the getType method like this;

```
static <T> Class<? super T> getType(final T instance) {
// returns a Class which is parent of given instance.
}

static void invokeDoSomething(){
        A instance = new A();
        Class<? super A> type = getType(instance);
        doSomethind(type, instance);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics with "`<? super E>`" are always a little tricky and I always found a way around it. Maybe you can do to.

I don't exactly what you want to do, but what happens if you try to call?

```
doSomething(String.class, "foo");
```

With `<? super T>` you can also do:

```
doSomething(Object.class, "foo");
```

That wouldn't be possible with just Class.

Answer (score 1):

This should make your pain go away

```
//a target method to call
static <T> void doSomething(final Class<? super T> type, final T instance) {
}

//returns a super of T as you pointed out
static <T> Class<? super T> getType(final T instance) {
}

static <T> void doSomething(final T instance) {
    final Class<? super T> type= getType(instance);
    //call to doSomething with a type and an instance
    doSomething(type, instance);
}
```